# Crash logs generated by iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, crash-reports

Are there any crash logs generated by iPhone Simulator?

the Simulator crashes a lot but not leaving any traces in Console... the crash log will be useful.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need the crash logs. When the app in the simulator crashes but before you stop the debugging, at the gdb prompt type "bt" for "backtrace" -- you'll get exactly what would appear in the crash log. (didn't realize there was question necromancy here, missed the post year)

Comment: If the crash only occurred when you weren't attached by the debugger then you would need the logs.

Comment: you're right. this make sense!

Comment: You can also see the debug log (including output of lldb commands) in the "Report navigator" in Xcode (cmd-8).  This is useful for seeing the debug output for previous runs too.  If the debugger wasn't attached, then this won't work obviously.

Comment: Debug log is not the same as Crash log, though both logs are useful to debug the problem.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The console will show the `NSLog()` output from an app running in the simulator. The crash logs are saved to file.

I have found some in my home directory under

```
~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/
```

They have a file extension of `.crash`

Something I haven't yet figured out is how to get them to generate even if the debugger grabs the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` signal.

---

**Update**

Currently, (OSX 10.11.6), the .crash logs in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`, are when *the emulator itself crashes*.  Logs for an *app* crashing (but the emulator device is still running fine), are in:

> ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator

Per crash, there is a sub-folder with a unique id. Sort by date, so that your recent crash is the first sub-folder. Inside that, start by looking at `stderr.log` and `system.log`.

Also directly under `CoreSimulator`, see `CoreSimulator.log` and `Simulator.log`.

Comment: Any idea why these logs are written to file instead of showing up in the console? Thanks for the info, btw.

Comment: None of my crash reports in iPhone or iPad simulator show up under this directory, maybe this answer needs to be updated?

Comment: Perhaps it does need an update, but a down vote isn't a very polite way to encourage it.

Comment: @Justin This answer is still valid November '12 so I doubt the answer was incorrect (needed updating) a year ago.

Comment: from other SO question, there is a (seem-to-be) valid answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11228598/188331

Comment: I found the crash report in the mentioned directory, but there was only one report and it was not the most recent one (i.e., I kept trying a few things in the app and it kept crashing). The crashes were all the same, so it wasn't an issue, but I am wondering if this is generally the case?

Comment: Both Justin and ohhorob are correct.  You need to launch the app on the simulator WITHOUT Xcode and reproduce the crash to see the logs in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`

Comment: In my DiagnosticReports directory no any .crash files.

Comment: On OSX 10.11.6, the .crash logs in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`, are when *the emulator itself crashes*.  Logs for an app crashing (but the emulator is still running fine), I see in `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator`.

Comment: As @DaveChambers said, dbl-click the app in the Simulator, watch it crash, then go to `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`, or, in the `Console` app open `DiagnosticReports`. I really needed this info - mid-2019 using latest Xcode/MacOS etc.

Comment: I see logs for an app crashing (but the emulator is still running fine) inside `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` not `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/`.

Answer (score 22):

I am pretty sure that you can see this in the OS X Console app located in Utilities. If I'm wrong though, be sure to vote me the heck down so I delete this.

---

UPDATE:

Specifically (as of OSX 10.11.6),

When an app crashes on emulator, a subfolder (with a unique id) is added to:

> ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator

Within that, start by examining `stderr.log` and `system.log`.

When the emulator *itself* crashes, a subfolder is added to:

> ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

Don't confuse this path with

> /Library/Logs

(lacking `~` at start), which has different reports about your mac.

Comment: Yep. More info here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html

Comment: seems that it only applies to iPhone devices, instead of simulator. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The Console can be opened from the simulator by pressing Cmd-/ or using the Debug/Open System Log... menu option.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s something that worked for me in a special case...  My app was crashing with SIGKILL as it terminated.  I would see the exception in main.m for a few seconds, and then the app would finish terminating – thus, no chance to get the back trace.

I did a lot of searching on “where does simulator store its crash logs” and never managed to find an answer.  However, the following trick came in quite handy and I was able to grab the crash log on the fly:

Basically, open /Applications/Utilities/CrashReporterPrefs.app and change the setting to “Developer”.  This will cause CrashReporter to display a popup with the crash log after your app crashes.

I found this in the “Viewing iOS Simulator Console and Crash Logs” section in this doc from Apple: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html

Comment: By the way, the original problem with SIGKILL that I was researching turned out to be a non-issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901262/xcode-debugger-stops-with-sigkill-on-stop-button

Comment: I should point out that there was no CrashReporterPrefs app in Application/Utilities, however I searched for it and was able to find the app elsewhere.

Comment: @Justin where did you find it?

Comment: Note that the tool referred to above is downloadable from Xcode in a bundle called "Additional Tools for Xcode" https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=additional%20tools%20for%20xcode

Answer (score 2):

The crash crash logs will appear under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter.

- If the iPhone simulator program crashes (not the iPhone app running within the simulator), then there will be an entry for iPhoneSimulator.
- If the iPhone App within the simulator crashes, the crash log will appear with the display name of the app.

When Xcode gets crash logs from a connected device, it stores them in sub-folders of ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice

Comment: This is over a year later but I see the "app within simulator" crashes at ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports ... and it looks like: MobileSafari_2013-03-21-155844_My-MacBook-Pro.crash

Answer (score 1):

This is much more reliable. In only a few steps I was able to find the source line number & method name:

1. cd to the dir having the .app & .dSYM files
2. run /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-arm-apple-darwin MyApp.app/MyApp
3. set print asm-demangle on
4. set print symbol-filename on
5. p/a 0×00015c64 -> address got by opening the crash log in “Console” app or just double clicking the the .crash file.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need the crash logs. When the app in the simulator crashes but before you stop the debugging, at the gdb prompt type "bt" for "backtrace" -- you'll get exactly what would appear in the crash log.

Comment: This method works great for the crash logs from client phones.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an expression that I had added to the debugger watch window. When a breakpoint was getting hit, the bad expression was causing XCode to segfault.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14984297/679240

None of the answers above worked on the "Big Sur" OS version. The only way to find the log was through the "Console" app (Application/Utilities/Console)