# "The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP)", only when NOT debugging

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator, breakpoints

I am developing with Xcode 3.2.5 for the iPhone. When testing my program in the simulator, I get this error immediately when my program starts and crashes

> The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP)

But if I activate debugging, even if there are not breakpoints, the program runs perfectly.

Do you know where to start looking at?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting Xcode and click "Clean all targets", that might help.

Comment: I did it all lots of times, it's a problem that has been with this project for a long time. Is there a way to make a "deeper clean" than with "clean all targets"?

Comment: I don't think so... Have you tried to build it using 'Release'?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same problem. Do you think that this could be a problem when submitting the app?

Comment: I don't really know. But I think I would try to locate the problem. Have you tried to google it? Obviously there is something wrong somewhere. Have you tried changing the base sdk? I've read about someone who had the same problem, he re-imported the graphics and then added them again without copy them to the project.

Comment: I finally had to re create the whole project, starting from a blank xcode project and adding all the graphics and sources. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer suggests you can look at the simulator's crash logs to find a stack trace. This might help narrow down the search:

[Crash logs generated by iPhone Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864479/crash-logs-generated-by-iphone-simulator)

Does the program run OK on the device itself?

Comment: in the device it worked perfectly. When I recreated the project adding the files from the old project, it started working in the simulator too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, clean build didn't help. I eventually reset the simulator and removed all the files in the .xcodeproj folders that weren't project.pbxproj (ie: all the jim.* files etc).

I should have done one at a time because now I don't know which fixed the problem, but now it works.