# Unable to run app in Simulator Xcode 6

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

Yesterday i was testing my app in the iOS simulator and everything was working fine. I then decided to run the app on my iPhone and i got the error `unable to install application, Unknown error occurred` this has happened before so I cleaned my build folder (as this has fixed this issue before) however, the same error occurred. I then ran the app in the iOS simulator again and now i get the error `Unable to run app in Simulator, An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)`. I find this very weird as i didn't change anything besides trying to run the app on my iPhone. I have tried every solution given on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130558/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain) and still no luck.

I'm sorry if my question doesn't contain much detail but as I said I didn't change anything and it was building and running fine a minute before plugging in my iPhone and trying to run it on there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

*edit*

I tried running other projects (with and without extensions) and they are working on both simulator and iPhone, therefore the problem must be within my project. (my project does have a today extension)

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Answer (score 4):

In that kind of cases I usually :

- Product > Clean
- Close xCode
- Delete the Derived Data (in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData subfolders)
- Delete the app on the iPhone
- Reboot the iPhone
- Restart and rebuild

Comment: thanks for the response, just tried it now and still got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem.  In my case, it was caused by the Build value being blank.  After putting a value there, and resetting the simulator once more, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889189/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain/25894677#25894677) and checking the system log carefully helped me to identify a coliding library that was causing this error. You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25281060/4050104) if you are using extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it means there is a problem with the build, it may be due to old cache (solved by a clean build) or a project definition error (missing library, bad definition in info.plist, etc).

In my case it happened only on iOS 8, turns out that my widget had the wrong bundle ID.