# This app could not be installed at this time. Could not hardlink copy. (on second run)

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, simulator

I keep getting this error when building a react-native app.

I can get rid of this by uninstalling the app on iOS simulator or "Erase all Contents and Settings" from the simulator. However, earlier in the project, I didn't have to do this.

I have looked at a number of different solutions but nothing seems to be correct.

- There are both Version and Build number
- `CFBundleShortVersionString` is `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`
- `CFBundleVersion` is 253
- There is a `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` but it also has the same `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` as above
- There aren't multiple InfoPlist.string files
- I've tried deleting DerivedData
- I've re-installed all pods
- `plutil Info.plist` returns OK

Other links include:

- [Xcode: "This app could not be installed at this time."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760643/xcode-this-app-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time)
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47135

However, I cant get to the bottom of the issue...

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS simulator: could not hardlink copy. Wrong path in my filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167020/ios-simulator-could-not-hardlink-copy-wrong-path-in-my-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was one of the pods which i included into project. i found out that one of them was Beta. excluded, cleaned everything and no problem right now..

namely : Firebase / Crashlytics