# Xcode displays error when trying to run app without uninstall from simulator (multi configuration files)

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode displays this error every time i run the app on simulator , he forces me to uninstall the app first before every run .

i have 3 .xcconfig files on this project , Is the problem can be related to this? because all other projects are running fine without uninstall.

Xcode is Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

[image: xcode error]

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Window>Devices and then click simulators. This shows a list of all your simulators. Delete any duplicates.

After that I would look for anything that stands out in your info.plist and in your project under "Build Settings" or "Signing and Capabilities".

These might also help:
[iOS simulator: could not hardlink copy. Wrong path in my filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167020/ios-simulator-could-not-hardlink-copy-wrong-path-in-my-filesystem)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/67294