# In the latest version of XCode, why does the simulator not run even with a settings reset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios-simulator

I get this error when I try running my app in the simulator. The error is:

> An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)

I tried changing the name of the app and this happened.
Furthermore, I tried cleaning the product and it didn't do anything, still having the same error of:

> Unable to run app in Simulator. An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code=0)

I also tried changing the name back to what it used to be in the Info file which you can see at `postimg.org/image/erieubblp/`. But it didn't change anything.
If you need anything else let me know.

I've also done a Reset content and settings on the simulator.

Also, I checked all the other forum posts on this error and nothing worked.

Comment: Just Reset your simulator

Comment: I've done that @MuhammadWaqas but it didn't change anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log and ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[Device UDID]/system.log at the time the error occurred for more specific information about the error.

If that doesn't help you, please amend your question with the exact text of the error as printed in CoreSimulator.log and the relevant lines from installd in system.log, and I will update my answer as well.

Also see my answer to [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be solved by:-

1. Reset simulator
2. Delete derived data
3. clean project and run

Comment: Hi @Mayank Jain, this doesn't seem to work. Although, what does derived data mean?

Answer (score 1):

1.Just Quit your simulator
2.Clean your application
3.Run your app .So that the problem will be resolved

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Suneha, I've done that as I've said before. It doesn't seem to resolve the problem.