# An error occurred while running my app in simulator (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)

Tags: frameworks, xcode6, ios-simulator

I am working on both a framework and an app that is using the framework. I have setup the bundle id and provisional profile to be the same for both the framework and the app so they can be uploaded to testflight (that's how I did it a month ago). However this time the error shows up in Xcode and is unable to run in simulator.

Does anyone know what the problems is?

Bundle ID: com.xxxxx.sdk-app (the same for both app and framework)

Provisional profile: iOS distribution (Ad Hoc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Comment: feedbacks in there doesn't fix my problem..