# An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)?

Tags: ios, xcode6, lipo, ios-universal-framework

I am working on a framework, I created a universal .framework package using Lipo command. If try to integrate with a test app and try to install on simulator I am getting An error was encountered while running `(Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)` ?

It would be great if any one help me on this issue

Thanks

kumar

Comment: Add some relevant code to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)