# iOS watch app Watch Framework issue

Tags: ios, ios9, watchkit, ios-frameworks

Hello guys I am trying to add watch framework in my project. So that I can reuse the code.

But as soon as I add Watch Framework and when I try to run the app, I am getting the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

Also i gone through the log file CoreSimulator.log i am getting this error

`watch kit 2 app has framework that's not allowed`

[image]

[image]

Also I set my Project Deployment target to iOS 9.

The naming convention of bundle identifier is also proper.

Comment: Can you put down bundle identifier of your watch extension and app?

Comment: app  bundle id is `com.exa.au.digitalanniversaries` and Watch Framework bundle id is `com.exa.au.dawatchkit`

Comment: Please check this. Are you following the same? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097067/xcode-6-2-watchkit-sample-app-doesnt-start-the-operation-couldn-t-be-complete

Comment: Also check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0/26129829#26129829

Comment: Where as I see you have com.exa.au.digitalanniversaries this is your bundle identifier So  Watch framework bundle identifier should be com.exa.au.digitalanniversaries.watchkitextension according to one answer. Isn't it?

Comment: I am talking about the problem which can be a reason for that

Comment: no that sud be with parent bundle identifier,its correct.Bcz i can run  app without Watch Framework

Comment: OK I am searching a solution for that but when you are adding framework to your app make it optional, Perhaps it can solve the problem.

Comment: No @iEinstein it didnt worked, i added screenshot ,which i am trying to do

Comment: OK @muku Sorry but I didn't do too much work on watchkit but I will try to answer you with one of my friend's help :) .