# Xcode emulating app LaunchServicesError error 0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm new to the business of creating apps. I've been struggling with Xcode for a while now, going back and forth with probs. So I've got completely stuck at a particular problem which I can't seem to figure out.

What happens is when I build my app, everything is successful. But when I want to run it in a simulator, I get the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

I've tried to read the systemlog error messages, which tells me that something fails to copy. This is sort of too deep into the system for me to understand. Here's the text:

> 2015-07-08 15:23:09,208
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[406]: Error
>   Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7f8a3999e660
>   {Error=PackageExtractionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to copy
>   file:///Users/anton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FinalApp-fxvfoxhwlmzevnbnrxjrugytqlpc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FinalApp.app/
>   to
>   file:///Users/anton/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5128280-9715-4EB2-9AF4-398AC81C1D66/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.QnGIi8/extracted/FinalApp.app}

Also here is my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon.png</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-50</string>
          <string>icon-76</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.alkaloida.publish</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.0.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I hope someone out there have some info about what the heck is going on.. Because I really don't.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the top answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0) shed any light?

Comment: I have actually read that like three times. As I am fairly new to this whole info.plist thing I can't tell what's right or wrong.. I could post the code fr there aswell if it is to any help?

Comment: @AntonBergenudd, did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes I did solve the problem. The problem is still sort of unknown, but after I tore the whole project apart. I got to the conclusion that it was one of my images that was messing things up. I still don't know how.