# Simulator fails with (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I always see error:

```
(Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)
```

When trying to launch my app in the iOS Simulator with Xcode 6.4. I looked through all solutions proposed here, but nothing works!

I tried to follow the answer of
[Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)
but simply don't understand, what's going on!

Does anybody understand this error message in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log:

> Jul 28 08:19:54 PetersMacBookPro.local com.apple.dt.Xcode[67331] : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7f802f5c2de0 {Error=PackagePatchFailed, ErrorDescription=Could not hardlink copy /Users/petervonwalter/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C67C25D6-CA40-4EFC-8C8C-05040CD925C8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/505FD1CE-539A-4BB2-9AF3-7E257451C440/Formulary.app to /Users/petervonwalter/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C67C25D6-CA40-4EFC-8C8C-05040CD925C8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iu6MMQ/extracted/Payload/Formulary.app with manifest /Users/petervonwalter/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C67C25D6-CA40-4EFC-8C8C-05040CD925C8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iu6MMQ/extracted/com.apple.deltainstallcommands.com.vwa.formulary}

Comment: As i said, i cannot find a solution there (i think i tried everything) but also do not understand the (detailed) error message!
Does anybody find a specific reason?

Comment: Installation is failing because installd cannot hardlink.  This can happen for various reasons, some of which were fixed back in iOS 8.2 and some of which were addressed later (maybe 8.3 or 9.0), but you should be able to use the simulator in most configurations without issue so long as you don't have multiple file systems involved or filesystems that don't support hard links.