# LaunchServicesError error 0. when launching app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've dug into several threads ([here](http://Xcode%20emulating%20app%20LaunchServicesError%20error%200), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669812/simulator-fails-with-launchserviceserror-error-0), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019981/the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-launchserviceserror-error-0) to name a few) but I just cannot figure this out. I've cleared cache, reset the simulator, tripled checked .plist files, cloned my repo again, and even reinstalled Xcode.

And here's the rub - the same repo works on my other machine. Here is log error:

```
Oct  8 09:51:09  CoreSimulatorService[1941] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: Failed to lookup com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: 0x44e
Oct  8 09:51:11  com.apple.dt.Xcode[1927] <Error>: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=ExecutableTwiddleFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to chmod file:///Users/Jason/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0593D533-2974-4464-937C-B77EC0299078/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Temp/Bundle/Application/FA2B923A-1015-43E5-BA59-716BBD114A3D/Test.app/PlugIns/TestActionExtension.appex/TestActionExtension : No such file or directory}
```

I also tried clearing the cache where it's looking for the extension that's giving me issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0/26129829#26129829 for more specifics about this error.  Thanks for actually providing the real underlying error instead of just the "LaunchServicesError 0".  I haven't see this ENOENT when chmoding error before.  Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and include a sample project.

Comment: I'll definitely do that @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia - thanks for the advice. To any other viewers, literally the only way I could fix this was to delete and readd the extension