# iOS Simulator fails to launch when adding Watch Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, watchkit, watchos-2

My iPhone app launches in the simulator just fine until I add a Watch Framework from `New > Target > watchOS > Watch Framework`. Once I add the framework target I get the "The operation couldn’t be completed (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" error.

I've tried `"Reset Content and Settings"` in the simulator.

I've tried deleting all simulators from my computer and re-adding them.

I've cleaned the build folder.

I've done everything I can think of or find, but no one else seems to be reporting this issue.

Xcode 7.0, iOS 9 simulator

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0/26129829#26129829 ... CoreSimulator.log and the sim device's system.log should provide you more detailed error messages.

Comment: hey did u got solution .Even i am facing this issue?