# AFNetworking 2.0 requests hanging in Today Extension and Watch app in iOS 9 / WatchOS 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have encountered a very strange and frustrating issue when building WatchKit and Today extensions using Xcode 7 (GM) as well as Xcode 7.1 (beta 1). Using AFNetworking 2.0 (up to date as of this posting), I call the following code from any of these extensions:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager GET:endpoint parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
}];
NSLog(@"Called!");
```

The expectation here would be that one of the two blocks would be called after `Called!` is logged. However, neither one is ever executed.

Strangely, however, if I call the following line:

```
[op cancel];
```

I get the expected `failure` block's log outputted. Nothing else I've tried (turning off Internet connectivity on my computer, creating a nonsense URL, etc.) has been able to get the `failure` block to execute.

At this point I'm not sure if I've been trying to debug this too late into the night, if this is a bug with Xcode 7.x, or if I'm making a mistake somewhere. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this problem stemmed from a couple of different things.

The base of the problem is iOS 9's new App Transport Security rules. These rules can be [overridden using certain keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720929/1145804) in the app's `info.plist` file. However, I was having difficulty getting the override keys to save properly using Xcode 7.0 (GM) in the extensions because it would throw [an error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25632886/1145804) when attempting to run the project.

**Step 1**:
In Xcode 7.1 beta 1, the above keys are actually supported by Xcode (and even autocomplete), so I was able to add these keys to my WatchKit and today extension `info.plist` files:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

**Step 2**: At this point, AFNetworking was still hanging and wasn't allowing connections to go through. Even now I'm not sure why this is happening. Instead, I resorted to using the standard iOS classes for making network calls, which ended up finally resolving my problem and being able to run requests as usual:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *connection = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl.com/xyz"]];
[connection setValue:"Bearer myAuthorization" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:connection queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error == nil) {

        NSString *dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //Do stuff with data

    } else {

        //Error handling
    }
}];
```

Hopefully something here helps someone in the future. This was a complete nightmare for a good day and a half to figure out!