# Unable to run the Simulator The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7

Im trying to run the IOS9 iphone 6 app in Xcode 7 and swift 2.0, but I can't. 
If I reset the content and Simulator settings, the first time works but the second one fails again, I have cleaned up the app, I have cleaned the build folder, I have tried setting the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to yes, Sorry, but I have a headache searching what's going on. Appreciate help

the error in the coresimulator.log is

```
    07/10/15 21:51:02,800 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[410]: 
Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" 
UserInfo={Error=PackagePatchFailed, 
ErrorDescription=Could not hardlink copy
 /Users/edu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F25180D1-32CD-47E0-9823-D1626546D660/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7E6A0B88-3B33-435F-A645-3367B6F47154/vippler.app.ios.app 
to /Users/edu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F25180D1-32CD-47E0-9823-D1626546D660/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LDNqVX/extracted/Payload/vippler.app.ios.app 
with manifest /Users/edu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F25180D1-32CD-47E0-9823-D1626546D660/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LDNqVX/extracted/com.apple.deltainstallcommands.com.Bitamine.vippler-app-ios}
```

and the screenshot of the info.plist is

[image]

Comment: Many dupes.  Please search before posting questions.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0/26129829#26129829

Comment: Sorry but I tried all ways of this thread and the error persist

Comment: Then please update your question to include the underlying error.  As indicated in my answer (referenced above), the "LaunchServicesError 0" just indicates that something went wrong.  It does not indicate *what* went wrong.  You need to pull that information out of CoreSimulator.log and the device's system.log.

Comment: I've just edited the question, I hope its clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the screenshot, it's clear that your Info.plist is missing a CFBundleVersion ("Bundle Version") key.  If that key is missing, it can cause this problem.

Comment: What is the difference between "Bundle Version string, short" and "Bundle Version"?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the keys: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html --- CFBundleShortVersionString is localizable and not as restrictive.  CFBundleVersion needs to follow a strict versioning convention.

Answer (score 0):

Based on error description
Error=PackagePatchFailed, 
ErrorDescription=Could not hardlink copy
we would say the compiler couldn't find the path of the resource such as frameworks, images. But the main problem probably is Pod. So try to delete all the cached files by following these steps

1. command shift G
2. paste this path /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3. delete relevant finders
4. Reset Content and settings of the simulator
5. re-compile the project

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Changing the entire project root directory path seems to somehow work for me

Answer (score -1):

Make the Exception In Transport Security along with the  "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads"

Comment: The error described in the question is a build time error. Problems with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads can only be related to Runtime issues