# Unable to install the .app in my simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

While trying to  install .app in my ipad simulator  i get this error:

xcrun instruments -w 'iPad 2 (9.2)'

xcrun simctl install booted /Users/user/Downloads/Payload/Artinove.app

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=LaunchServicesError, code=0):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)