# Simulator LaunchServicesError error 0. - rename folder fixes it?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Suddenly I've started to get this error LaunchServiceError

If I rename the main folder say from ProjectA to ProjectB 
then the LaunchServiceError goes away, as soon as I name it back to the original folder name, the error returns.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Comment: See my response in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0/26129829#26129829 and provide more information if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error my guess is that you're not opening Xcode Instruments in the recommended ways:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/LaunchingInstruments.html

Basically always make sure you launch it through Xcode (or an Xcode application menu by right clicking on the Xcode icon, etc). As well, make sure to always save your .trace file using Save As in Instruments, so that you can ensure it's saved with a unique name.