# Unable to run app in Simulator: An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

After successfully compiling the project in Xcode 6, I am unable to run it in the simulator with the above mentioned message. I did all the possible research, tried everything and still no advances.

I am not working with swift, neither I use widgets or extensions, so please do not suggest solutions caused by these as can be seen in similar questions.

If someone found a possible cause (or solution!!) other than [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130558/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain), please help. Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful if you can list what you have tried to exclude those recommendations.

Comment: The issue is now resolved, but just for information I tried:
- running a clean
- removing the project cache/derived data
- restarting both Simulator and Xcode
- restarting the Mac
- reinstalling Xcode
- cleaning and reinstalling CocoaPods
- checking Build Settings for any rare appearances

Nothing helped. Did't try fiddling with app extensions naming as I do not use any.

Comment: "Product -> Clean" worked for me.

Comment: I had this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037589/xcode-6-1-installation-failed-invalid-argument-when-trying-to-run-today-appli#comment52061760_29645687

Comment: Restarting simulator solved my problem

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This has now been resolved. The problem was caused by ShareKit library added by CocoaPods for compatibility reasons. After removing the library and all related code, the app successfully launched in simulator. I recommend *checking the system log* for more details on the issue as to me it pointed me in the right direction (stating the name of conflicting library).

Comment: I just added shareKit and I have the same problem.

Comment: In case this helps anyone: You can access the system log by typing Console in Spotlight.

Comment: For me it was the MixpanelAppExtension

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out.  XCode 7.3.1 and my log showed "ErrorDescription=Could not hardlink copy". I was setting a version but not build number in Target -> General -> Identity.  Once I included a value for Build the problem went away.

Comment: To check system log try this command in Terminal:  tail -f /var/log/system.logiOS Simulator prints directly to stdout, so you can see the logs mixed up with system logs.

Comment: ShareKit was not my issue, but the recommendation to check the console log helped me track down the actual issue, which in my case was a bad bundle ID.

Comment: Myframework.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist

but everywhere the key is present

Answer (score 179):

**"Reset Content and Settings"** from **iOS Simutalor** menu options and launching simulator after **Quitting** solved my issue.

[image: Reset Content and Settings]

Comment: Way better than initial answer. Should be marked as the solution.

Comment: After that I also needed to quit and reopen the simulator.

Comment: This requirement is already mentioned in my answer @jfredsilva.

Comment: Also deleting the App if you had previously installed it on the simulator

Comment: Worked for me after also deleting Derived Data

Answer (score 126):

Cleaning the build folder resolved the issue for me.

(While holding down the **Alt**-key: **Product > Clean build folder**)

Comment: This worked for me after I updated to use Cocoapods and the .xcworkspace.

Comment: This is a must-do after updating to Cocoapods v1.0.0

Comment: Best answer so far, tried everything from resetting app + cleaning xcode to deleting and reinstalling all the pods, nothing worked until i found this.

Answer (score 33):

I tried every other solution listed here. Well, I ported my project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0. The application was stuck even after a lot debugging and launch services error 0 was reported.

solution: It happens because of framework compilation.

App target -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks.

So mark copy only when installing on. Clean the project and run it!

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more about how "Copy only when installing" fixes the problem?

Comment: @ sethfri :  "Copy only when installing" to specify that the build phase copies files only in install builds of the product.                                                          https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/CreatingaCopyFilesBuildPhase.html

Comment: I understand what the words "Copy only when installing" mean. I'm asking how this fixes the problem the question author is facing.

Answer (score 16):

In case anyone has this problem in combination with cocoa pods, these steps helped me to solve this error (after few hours):

- run `pod cache clean`
- from SRC_ROOT run `rm -rf Pods` (optionally `rm Podfile.lock`)
- Click on the **Simulator** app, click Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...
- Go into Xcode, In the Menu bar click Product -> Clean (or click Shift + Command + K).This will to clean your Xcode project.
- Create a new Terminal Shell (From menu bar click Shell -> New Window)
- run `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

...then try to Build & Run your project.

**Note:**
SRC_ROOT can be found by entering the **Navigator**, clicking on the project, clicking on the project again from the **project and targets list**, going into **Build Settings**, scrolling all the way to the bottom to the **User-Defined Section**, and the SRC_ROOT will be labeled as PODS_ROOT. Take that and copy it verbatum into the Terminal and proceed with step 2 from the list above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This did it. Thank you! Really should be the accepted answer.

Comment: That solved my issue! Definitely it should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 15):

I get rid from the issue by the given steps for simulator

**1. Way**

1. Reset Content and Settings of **Simulator**.
2. Clean your project by **Cmd+Shift+K**.
3. Clear your **Derived Data**.
4. The last one which is more important change your Bundle Identifier by **"com.yourcompanyname.projectname"** like **"com.facebook.Facebook"**

**2. Way**

You can do only be the given line, it works for me

The last one which is more important change your Bundle Identifier by **"com.yourcompanyname.projectname"** like **"com.facebook.Facebook"**

Thanks and enjoy programming.

Comment: Do you mean `cmd` instead of `win`? ;) (Or maybe you use a windows keyboard.)

Comment: @JeroenJK Yes its Cmd.

Comment: Wow, the bundle ID change is the one that finally worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Might be related to this issue: ["This app contains an app extension with an illegal bundle identifier" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007290/this-app-contains-an-app-extension-with-an-illegal-bundle-identifier-issue/31101836#31101836)

I had to format the bundle identifiers for my app and extension as follows:

```
com.company.AppName
com.company.AppName.Extension
```

Comment: Same here. I changed the bundle identifier because the extension(widget) was not showing up, and that caused it. Had to lower the extension version from 9.2 to 8.2 and change the bundle as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, exactly my problem!

Answer (score 6):

1. First "Reset Content and Settings"
2. If you didn't fill the build number and fill it and Run.

It's solved for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the name of the supplied class `InterfaceController` set by default when you start a new project. This class is referenced in the `Info.plist` under the key `RemoteInterfacePrincipalClass`. In my case, I got the error mentioned by the OP until I fixed the name of the class in there (see screenshot).

[image: Info.plist: set principal class]

Comment: That really helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out @Miki and kudos to you. I had the same issue as you yesterday (and I added ShareKit 3.0.0 from CocoaPods to the app a few days ago). I suspected ShareKit giving me this problem, but now I can be confident of exactly which library is causing this. Here is what I found in my log (if it can benefit others):

> Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7fa836097aa0
>   {Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to load
>   Info.plist from bundle at path
>   /Users/{UserName}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99FEB34E-6F00-4EFA-861A-A6985AFE96D8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.X7eead/extracted/{AppName}.app/Frameworks/LiveSDK.framework}

Comment: from your log, how can you know that ShareKit causes the error?

Comment: i have the same thing in my log but removing simulators and adding them back doesn't help... how did you fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are here after having issues doing an integration with WatchOS 2.0, go to - `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[Device UDID]/system.log` and if says something like `WatchKit 2 app has frameworks; that's not allowed.` then follow the link below.

http://zyafa.me/blog/watchos-2-and-embedded-frameworks

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the simulator log file.
In my case the log file at 
`~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log`
disclosed that my linked framework did not have a `CFBundleIdentifier` in its Info.plist

Comment: framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist : i'm also getting this what is the solution? not using on watchkit or watchOS

Answer (score 1):

I'm adMob user and I solved enabling "Copy only when installing" in App target -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem after localizing my app. Especially `Info.plist`. Seems I had empty `CFBundleShortVersionString` in `InfoPlist.strings`, after fixing that the simulator started to work properly.

Comment: That was my problem too. If you see that try to remove all keys that not requires localisation from your InfoPlist.strings files.

In my case removing keys below fixed everything:
CFBundleName
CFBundleShortVersionString
CFBundleVersion

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue by adding a folder reference named "Resources".

If I give it another name, then it runs !

Comment: This one solved me a similar issue! I was embedding a dylib, and it caused a cryptic "did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist" installation error. After changing the Resources folder to something else it started working again

Comment: Two birds with one stone ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that can cause this error. The best general answer is to search the console log for `CoreSimulator`, as the simulator logs the underlying problem when it displays this message.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed any libraries using `CocoaPods` while XCode was open, all you have to do is, Close XCode and remove the library from `Pod` file, run the command `pod install` it will uninstall that library. then install library again. Please make sure that XCode is always closed while installing and uninstalling libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I hade exactly the same problem and it was ShareKit.

On the simulator I had "Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0".

On the iPhone6 device I had "App installation failed Could not inspect the application package."

When I removed ShareKit it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I added an Apple Watch target to my app, and accidentally removed the InterfaceController.m file. Adding back the file in the target fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are different things that can cause this. Looking in the console may well give you a clue.

In my case - the issue was an extension built before I changed the name of the product. Xcode didn't clear the old one out, then got stressed at two extensions with the same bundle id.

(Deleting the build folder fixed my particular issue).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue came from an icon set added with some images missing.  Once I replaced the icon set with another one, and uninstalled the app in the simulator; I was able to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all my pod files and replaced them all, seems the problem for me was the bolts framework was old, and causing this error. I did a clean & reset content and now it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the google maps framework to the embedded lib section this solved my build break.

Comment: Removing the embedded framework that wasn't necessary to be there fixed my issue also

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in developing app for Apple Watch after adding in Info.plist: "App Transport Security Settings" and "Allow Arbitry Loads" = YES. (In WatchKit App, in WatchKit Extension is good!!)
Deleting this two rows, it keeps working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem occurs because I added my framework (`GoogleMobileAds.framework` in my case) to *Embedded Binaries*, not *Linked Frameworks and Libraries*.

For your information, AdMob instructs you to use `Add Files to "Your Project"` menu on Xcode, but I was too lazy to obey the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to run UI tests in a project containing AWS Cognito.

Here's how I resolved it.

1. Select the UI test target.
2. Click on the Build Phases section.
3. Click the plus to add a Copy Files phase
   [image: Add Copy Files phase]
4. In the Copy Files phase, change the destination to Frameworks (see the last image)
5. Hit the plus below the Copy Files phase.
6. Select the framework for which you're receiving an error and hit the Add button (yours will probably not be the first item in your project hierarchy).
   [image: Select Framework to copy]
   It should end up looking like this.
   [image: Final Result]
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 for all frameworks giving you an error.
8. Run your tests.