# "This app contains an app extension with an illegal bundle identifier" issue

Tags: xcode, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget, bundle-identifier

I'm a bit mixed up, since I changed the app name, Bundle Display name, and Bundle identifier name...and now my app works properly, but my today widget won't.

Whenever I try to run today widget, it builds successfully, but instead of being launched, it says

> This app contains an app extension with an illegal bundle identifier.
>   App extension bundle identifiers must have a prefix consisting of
>   their containing application's bundle identifier followed by a '.'.

However, I checked Info.plist and my bundle identifier is

> com.myname.myappname

and my bundle identifier of my today widget is

> com.myname.myappname.mywidget

Isn't this just right?? I cleaned and built again and again..but it just won't work.

And NO GOOGLE RESULT! Am I the only person with this problem??

My bundle name is not 'myappname', if it is the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Something's gone bad and I don't know where to look!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with the `Bundle identifier` in a share extension

## error

```
app Info.plist: com.company.product.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)
ext Info.plist: com.company.product.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)
```

So I ended up with

```
app Info.plist: com.company.product.product
ext Info.plist: com.company.product.product_ext
```

which passed the build checks but refused to run on a device with error:

> This app contains an app extension with an illegal bundle identifier. App extension bundle identifiers must have a prefix consisting of their containing application's bundle identifier followed by a '.'.

Once I removed the extra `product`, the build ran on a device.

## correct

```
app Info.plist: com.company.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)
ext Info.plist: com.company.product.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)

app Info.plist: com.company.product
ext Info.plist: com.company.product.product_ext
```

I discovered my error when I accidentally changed the application `Info.plist` instead of the extension `Info.plist`.  To aid in debugging the problem, introduce an error into the application `Info.plist`, and you should get a build error with the `Bundle identifier` of the app and extension:

```
 ERROR.com.myname.myappname
```

Comment: I cannot test your method since I already solved this problem by creating a new project and copying and pasting all my code to the new project...Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 33):

If the selected answer doesn't work, I found what appears to be an issue in xcode switching between some target schemas which caused this.

In this case, try doing a complete clean, as well as a clean of the build folder (hold down ALT when selecting product/clean).

**Addendum:**
As this happens fairly often for me now, a quicker fix is to also remove all .appex files.  Eg:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
find . -name "*.appex" -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

Comment: Clean of the build folder fixed this for me! I believe this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Sadly for me, both the accepted and this answer didn't work. Still getting the error. :/

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks.  I did previously change the extension name.  So I wonder if that had something to do with it.

Comment: Removed the DerivedData folder's contents. Clean and then built the project. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

For me this due to the misnamed bundle identifier for my app extension. Similar to @dougbeal's answer, but slightly different formatting that worked for me:

```
com.company.AppName
com.company.AppName.Extension
```

I was missing the `"."` before `Extension`

This also addressed a related to [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889189/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain)