# The apple watchkit app showing error "The operation couldn't be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)"

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch, targets, xcode-6.2

The apple watchkit app is not launching on simulator.
After renaming target always getting the message "The operation couldn't be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889189/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for this, is to have two different targets of WatchKit App in the same project. Attached capture from Console.app:

[image: capture]

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you didn't change anything in WatchApp plist file. You should have same bundle identifier (with .watchkitapp suffix) and WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier. And same for WatchAppExtension plist file.

BTW, I had a great problem, because we use many custom keys in plist, and you are not allowed to add them in WatchApp plist file it will cause the error.

P.S. Try launching it one the device it will show another error for sure!