# The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to run my app after changing the display name and bundle identifiers, but I keep running into this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)
```

I have tried many of the suggestions in other questions that have been asked such as cleaning the project, deleting derived data, changing bundle versions etc. but nothing seems to have helped. This is the plists that I have:

Main App

[image]

Watch Extension

[image]

Watch App

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: My Xcode 7.1 beta suddenly got this error. I did the following:

 1. Press Alt, Clean the Build folder
 2. Delete the derived the project data
 3. Goto simulator, and "Reset the content"
 4. Restart simulator and xcode

But still got the problem although it works for a lot of people based on the stackoverflow answers.

Comment: See my answer [here][1]  - it should solve your problem
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516284/the-apple-watchkit-app-showing-error-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-laun

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)