# How to fix a broken iOS Simulator (The operation couldn’t be completed. LaunchServicesError error 0.)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I try to run my project with my favorite simulators (iPhone 5s/8.4 and iPhone 5s/9.1) I get this error, and in syslog I see:

```
kernel[0]: AMFI: Simulator(pid 6881) - [deny-mmap] mapped file has no team identifier and is not a platform binary: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
```

This started happening after I had built and run an xcodeproject downloaded from github. My main project had been working fine and when I switched back to it, I started getting this error.

Other simulators, such as iPhone 6/9.1, work OK.

Previously, when switching back and forth between my own project and examples projects from the internet, I have seen xcode pop up a provisioning error alert, offering to fix the problem, and when I click "Fix" I am able to continue with no issue. I'm an xcode newbie and all this is quite mystifying.

I have tried to "Reset Content and Settings" of the offending simulator, Quit the Simulator, quit xcode, and rebooted. I've checked my Provisioning Profiles in Preferences > Accounts and they look fine as far as I can tell. 
Using the SimDir app I found the device directory for the simulator and dragged it to the trash. After that, the simulator worked for a little while then broke again.

I found [this apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html) but frankly I couldn't understand it (and I'm not running Swift. This is a react-native app.)

Oh one more thing. It's weird that the syslog message mentions `iOS 7.1.simruntime` when I'm using the 8.4 or 9.1 simulator. The project's deployment target is 7.0 but ???.

By the way I also tried cleaning my build folder (CMD-K) and anything else relevant in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889189/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25632886/1404185).

UPDATE: Like a virus, the working simulator is now getting infected. The iPhone 6/9.1 simulator worked well for a while, but now keeps getting this error (which can be 'fixed' temporarily by Reset Content and Settings). It looks like my Provisioning Profile is OK in xcode because I can run on my iPhone, and when I build an Archive of the project and validate it with Apple it validates succesfully. It's just the simulators.

Answer (score 1):

A good night's sleep resolved this issue! The next day I had the error pop up a couple of times but was resolved by "Reset Content and Settings". After that day the problem has not reappeared. I have no idea why I was seeing this... The only thing I can think of is that I might have had my own project and the example project from the web open in Xcode at the same time. You wouldn't think that should cause a problem but...

Answer (score 0):

If it has an Apple Watch App bundled in you should use the bundle IDs correctly, like:

```
com.user.app
com.user.app.watchkitapp
com.user.app.watchkitapp.watchkitextension
```