# My Xcode simulator doesn't start (React-native)

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

After starting a React-native app. and selecting ios Device I'm getting an error
day before everything worked fine.

> Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 60 An error was encountered
> processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60): Simulator
> device returned an error for the requested operation. Operation timed
> out Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=60):
> The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out
> Operation timed out

Tried Erasing Content things. Still ending up with this error

Comment: Can you start the emulator from Xcode?
Did you update Xcode, if yes did you accept the EULA

Comment: Sometimes it starts but mostly its just black screen nothing more..

Comment: Did you try to “Erase All content and settings” of the simulator.

Comment: As I mentioned before. I Did “Erase All content and settings” it works only for that time, after closing Xcode simulator and trying to launch again I'm ending with the same error

Comment: Du you try to use latest sim as Abhishek mentioned?

Comment: Yes I am using ios 17 and iphone 15. just Created a new app with npx create-expo-app . started and got the same error. Simulator turned on and just kept loading

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem . It's working fine with ios 17 in iphone 15 but rest previous simulators fail to start. I think this issue is due to xcode 15 update .

well I can't comment due to reputation not earned ,
try this link - [Unable to run app in Simulator: An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889189/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain)

btw most of the issues get resolved after restarting the device