# iOS Simulator - Launch Services Error 0

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to overcome an issue. I am having to reset my simulator setting every time before a generate a build otherwise I get the following error.

Any idea about how to overcome this issue?

Can anyone relate that to adding PubNub with pods to the project?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25281060/4475605

Comment: Non of that was helpful, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Comment: You need to provide the full error message.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0

Answer (score 5):

**"Reset Content and Settings"** from iOS Simutalor menu options and launching simulator after Quitting solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Resetting didn't quite fix it for me I had to do a full clean build for it to start running on the emulator again. Just hold down on the option key and from the Product menu select Clean build folder.

Comment: still not solved please help. i try to install cocoapod and on running in simulator the error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Check `CFBundleShortVersionString`, `CFBundleVersion` in `InfoPlist.plist` and `InfoPlist.strings` localization file, values should be the the same in both files.