# Xcode 7.3 The operation couldn't be completed (LaunchServicesError error 0)

Tags: ios, xcode

I've updated to Xcode 7.3 yesterday and can't really use the simulator since then. I always get this error as soon as I want to start to the app. 
When I deinstall the app on the simulator, everything works great. But that can't be a solution. This would take to long. I have also tried different simulators. On the iPhone itself it worked. I changed nothing since the upgrade

Comment: Have you renamed Xcode.app?

Comment: No I haven't. Neither did I change the bundle identifier

Comment: Have you try reset simulator a re-run xcode like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130558/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain

Comment: Yes, if I reset the simulator it works. Once. I would have to reset the simulator everytime I hit the run button. Similar to the deleting thing I do now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

May be it's because `CFBundleVersion` key/value pair in app's `Info.plist`.

If your app's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion key/value pair.

doing a "Reset Contents & Settings" will work, would be better to set an appropriate `CFBundleVersion` in the `Info.plist`.

you can check more error info in `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log` for error details also, more information about the problem in the simulated device's system log `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[Device UDID]/system.log`.

For more detail check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129829/5575752

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the problem. I had a look at recent commits and saw that I accidentally deleted the CFBundleVersion while removing the Facebook SDK from my project.,,.

Comment: it is still coming , i have Bundle identifier in my info.plist

Comment: Check  ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log to see error details, it will help@AbhishekThapliThapliyal

Answer (score 5):

"Reset Content and Settings" from iOS Simutalor menu options and launching simulator after Quitting may solve your issue.

In my case, Cleaning the build folder resolved the issue for me. I hope it helps someone!

(While holding down the **Alt-key: Product > Clean build folder**)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31155562/2564720