# Xcode 7.3.1 pop up a weird bug is LaunchServiceError error 0

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I run the project in simulator and got the weird bug is 'operation couldn't completed. (LaunchServiceError error 0) and after app was deleted from simulator.[image]

Comment: Some times this link will help :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130558/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain

OR

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632886/an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain-launchserviceserror-code-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS Simulator > Reset Contents and Settings...